# How can I export data to an aligned .txt file using a dataset in C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to export some data in a perfectly grid like aligned .txt file using a dataset. What i was trying to do worked with 5 and 25 columns, but i can't make it work for 60 columns. Is there any alternative?

I already tried using if with tab characters (because the columns don't get aligned due to some columns having less digits than the rest)

```
DataTable mytable = new DataTable("mytable");
objDataAdaptermytable.Fill(mytable);
var builder3 = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in mytable.Rows)
{
    int count = row.ItemArray[2].ToString().Length;
    int count2 = row.ItemArray[3].ToString().Length;
    int count3 = row.ItemArray[4].ToString().Length;
    int count4 = row.ItemArray[7].ToString().Length;
    MessageBox.Show(count2.ToString());
    if (count == 6)
    {
        builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2])+ ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[3] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[4], row.ItemArray[5], row.ItemArray[6], row.ItemArray[7], row.ItemArray[8], row.ItemArray[9], row.ItemArray[10], row.ItemArray[11], row.ItemArray[12], row.ItemArray[13], row.ItemArray[14], row.ItemArray[15], row.ItemArray[16], row.ItemArray[17], row.ItemArray[18], row.ItemArray[19], row.ItemArray[20], row.ItemArray[21], row.ItemArray[22], row.ItemArray[23], row.ItemArray[24], row.ItemArray[25], row.ItemArray[26], row.ItemArray[27], row.ItemArray[28], row.ItemArray[29], row.ItemArray[30], row.ItemArray[31], row.ItemArray[32], row.ItemArray[33], row.ItemArray[34], row.ItemArray[35], row.ItemArray[36], row.ItemArray[37], row.ItemArray[38], row.ItemArray[39], row.ItemArray[40], row.ItemArray[41], row.ItemArray[42], row.ItemArray[43], row.ItemArray[44], row.ItemArray[45], row.ItemArray[46], row.ItemArray[47], row.ItemArray[48], row.ItemArray[49], row.ItemArray[50], row.ItemArray[51], row.ItemArray[52], row.ItemArray[53], row.ItemArray[54], row.ItemArray[55], row.ItemArray[56], row.ItemArray[57], row.ItemArray[58], row.ItemArray[59])));
        if (count2 == 6)
        {
            builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2]) + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[3] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t"  + row.ItemArray[4] + "; " + "\t" + "\t"+ (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t",  row.ItemArray[5], row.ItemArray[6], row.ItemArray[7], row.ItemArray[8], row.ItemArray[9], row.ItemArray[10], row.ItemArray[11], row.ItemArray[12], row.ItemArray[13], row.ItemArray[14], row.ItemArray[15], row.ItemArray[16], row.ItemArray[17], row.ItemArray[18], row.ItemArray[19], row.ItemArray[20], row.ItemArray[21], row.ItemArray[22], row.ItemArray[23], row.ItemArray[24], row.ItemArray[25], row.ItemArray[26], row.ItemArray[27], row.ItemArray[28], row.ItemArray[29], row.ItemArray[30], row.ItemArray[31], row.ItemArray[32], row.ItemArray[33], row.ItemArray[34], row.ItemArray[35], row.ItemArray[36], row.ItemArray[37], row.ItemArray[38], row.ItemArray[39], row.ItemArray[40], row.ItemArray[41], row.ItemArray[42], row.ItemArray[43], row.ItemArray[44], row.ItemArray[45], row.ItemArray[46], row.ItemArray[47], row.ItemArray[48], row.ItemArray[49], row.ItemArray[50], row.ItemArray[51], row.ItemArray[52], row.ItemArray[53], row.ItemArray[54], row.ItemArray[55], row.ItemArray[56], row.ItemArray[57], row.ItemArray[58], row.ItemArray[59])));
            if (count3 == 6)
            {
                builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2]) + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[3] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[4] + "; " + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[5], row.ItemArray[6], row.ItemArray[7], row.ItemArray[8], row.ItemArray[9], row.ItemArray[10], row.ItemArray[11], row.ItemArray[12], row.ItemArray[13], row.ItemArray[14], row.ItemArray[15], row.ItemArray[16], row.ItemArray[17], row.ItemArray[18], row.ItemArray[19], row.ItemArray[20], row.ItemArray[21], row.ItemArray[22], row.ItemArray[23], row.ItemArray[24], row.ItemArray[25], row.ItemArray[26], row.ItemArray[27], row.ItemArray[28], row.ItemArray[29], row.ItemArray[30], row.ItemArray[31], row.ItemArray[32], row.ItemArray[33], row.ItemArray[34], row.ItemArray[35], row.ItemArray[36], row.ItemArray[37], row.ItemArray[38], row.ItemArray[39], row.ItemArray[40], row.ItemArray[41], row.ItemArray[42], row.ItemArray[43], row.ItemArray[44], row.ItemArray[45], row.ItemArray[46], row.ItemArray[47], row.ItemArray[48], row.ItemArray[49], row.ItemArray[50], row.ItemArray[51], row.ItemArray[52], row.ItemArray[53], row.ItemArray[54], row.ItemArray[55], row.ItemArray[56], row.ItemArray[57], row.ItemArray[58], row.ItemArray[59])));
                if (count4==6)
                {
                    builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2]) + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[3] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[4] + "; " + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[5], row.ItemArray[6], row.ItemArray[7]+";"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+ row.ItemArray[8]+";" + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[9], row.ItemArray[10], row.ItemArray[11], row.ItemArray[12], row.ItemArray[13], row.ItemArray[14], row.ItemArray[15], row.ItemArray[16], row.ItemArray[17], row.ItemArray[18], row.ItemArray[19], row.ItemArray[20], row.ItemArray[21], row.ItemArray[22], row.ItemArray[23], row.ItemArray[24], row.ItemArray[25], row.ItemArray[26], row.ItemArray[27], row.ItemArray[28], row.ItemArray[29], row.ItemArray[30], row.ItemArray[31], row.ItemArray[32], row.ItemArray[33], row.ItemArray[34], row.ItemArray[35], row.ItemArray[36], row.ItemArray[37], row.ItemArray[38], row.ItemArray[39], row.ItemArray[40], row.ItemArray[41], row.ItemArray[42], row.ItemArray[43], row.ItemArray[44], row.ItemArray[45], row.ItemArray[46], row.ItemArray[47], row.ItemArray[48], row.ItemArray[49], row.ItemArray[50], row.ItemArray[51], row.ItemArray[52], row.ItemArray[53], row.ItemArray[54], row.ItemArray[55], row.ItemArray[56], row.ItemArray[57], row.ItemArray[58], row.ItemArray[59])))));
                }
            }
        }
        if (count2 == 6)
        {
            builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2]) + ";" + "\t" + "\t"  + row.ItemArray[3] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[4] + "; " + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[5], row.ItemArray[6], row.ItemArray[7], row.ItemArray[8], row.ItemArray[9], row.ItemArray[10], row.ItemArray[11], row.ItemArray[12], row.ItemArray[13], row.ItemArray[14], row.ItemArray[15], row.ItemArray[16], row.ItemArray[17], row.ItemArray[18], row.ItemArray[19], row.ItemArray[20], row.ItemArray[21], row.ItemArray[22], row.ItemArray[23], row.ItemArray[24], row.ItemArray[25], row.ItemArray[26], row.ItemArray[27], row.ItemArray[28], row.ItemArray[29], row.ItemArray[30], row.ItemArray[31], row.ItemArray[32], row.ItemArray[33], row.ItemArray[34], row.ItemArray[35], row.ItemArray[36], row.ItemArray[37], row.ItemArray[38], row.ItemArray[39], row.ItemArray[40], row.ItemArray[41], row.ItemArray[42], row.ItemArray[43], row.ItemArray[44], row.ItemArray[45], row.ItemArray[46], row.ItemArray[47], row.ItemArray[48], row.ItemArray[49], row.ItemArray[50], row.ItemArray[51], row.ItemArray[52], row.ItemArray[53], row.ItemArray[54], row.ItemArray[55], row.ItemArray[56], row.ItemArray[57], row.ItemArray[58], row.ItemArray[59])));
            if (count3 == 6)
            {
                builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2]) + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[3] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[4] + "; " + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[5], row.ItemArray[6], row.ItemArray[7], row.ItemArray[8], row.ItemArray[9], row.ItemArray[10], row.ItemArray[11], row.ItemArray[12], row.ItemArray[13], row.ItemArray[14], row.ItemArray[15], row.ItemArray[16], row.ItemArray[17], row.ItemArray[18], row.ItemArray[19], row.ItemArray[20], row.ItemArray[21], row.ItemArray[22], row.ItemArray[23], row.ItemArray[24], row.ItemArray[25], row.ItemArray[26], row.ItemArray[27], row.ItemArray[28], row.ItemArray[29], row.ItemArray[30], row.ItemArray[31], row.ItemArray[32], row.ItemArray[33], row.ItemArray[34], row.ItemArray[35], row.ItemArray[36], row.ItemArray[37], row.ItemArray[38], row.ItemArray[39], row.ItemArray[40], row.ItemArray[41], row.ItemArray[42], row.ItemArray[43], row.ItemArray[44], row.ItemArray[45], row.ItemArray[46], row.ItemArray[47], row.ItemArray[48], row.ItemArray[49], row.ItemArray[50], row.ItemArray[51], row.ItemArray[52], row.ItemArray[53], row.ItemArray[54], row.ItemArray[55], row.ItemArray[56], row.ItemArray[57], row.ItemArray[58], row.ItemArray[59])));
                if (count4 == 6)
                {
                    builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1], row.ItemArray[2]) + ";" + "\t" + "\t"  + row.ItemArray[3] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[4] + "; " + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[5], row.ItemArray[6], row.ItemArray[7] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + row.ItemArray[8] + ";" + "\t" + "\t" + (String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray[9], row.ItemArray[10], row.ItemArray[11], row.ItemArray[12], row.ItemArray[13], row.ItemArray[14], row.ItemArray[15], row.ItemArray[16], row.ItemArray[17], row.ItemArray[18], row.ItemArray[19], row.ItemArray[20], row.ItemArray[21], row.ItemArray[22], row.ItemArray[23], row.ItemArray[24], row.ItemArray[25], row.ItemArray[26], row.ItemArray[27], row.ItemArray[28], row.ItemArray[29], row.ItemArray[30], row.ItemArray[31], row.ItemArray[32], row.ItemArray[33], row.ItemArray[34], row.ItemArray[35], row.ItemArray[36], row.ItemArray[37], row.ItemArray[38], row.ItemArray[39], row.ItemArray[40], row.ItemArray[41], row.ItemArray[42], row.ItemArray[43], row.ItemArray[44], row.ItemArray[45], row.ItemArray[46], row.ItemArray[47], row.ItemArray[48], row.ItemArray[49], row.ItemArray[50], row.ItemArray[51], row.ItemArray[52], row.ItemArray[53], row.ItemArray[54], row.ItemArray[55], row.ItemArray[56], row.ItemArray[57], row.ItemArray[58], row.ItemArray[59])))));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        builder3.AppendLine(String.Join(";" + "\t" + "\t", row.ItemArray));
    }
}
File.WriteAllText(@".\test.txt", builder3.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("Data exported");
cnn.Close();
}
```

I get a partially allingned .txt, like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiXJ6.jpg

Comment: Is using tabs a requirement?  And if so how do you determine your tab spacing?

Comment: No, it isn't. It is just required for the data of each column to be perfectly aligned one after another. My default is two tabs per column, and 3 tabs where the previous column data has 6 digits. My problem is that with 60 columns it just gets messy, so i am looking for an alternative that ideally doesn't use tab alignment, but default grid alignment, i don't care about how much the spacing will be.

Comment: looks like you just need to find the longest data value for each column in the whole data set. Then you know the smallest widths you can make your columns.

Comment: Do you mean that i should take lengths for every column of the dataset, and determine my tabs according to the longest values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of aligning it with `tab` you will need to pad the values (`PadLeft(int)` right-aligns the characters in this instance by padding them with spaces on the left, for a specified total length)

```
DataTable mytable = new DataTable("mytable");
objDataAdaptermytable.Fill(mytable);
var builder3 = new StringBuilder();

// find the longest occurring value for each column
int[] maxLengthPerColumn = new int[mytable.Columns.Count];
foreach (DataRow row in mytable.Rows) {
  for (int column = 0; column < mytable.Columns.Count; column++) {
    maxLengthPerColumn[column] = Math.Max(maxLengthPerColumn[column], row.ItemArray[column].ToString().Length);
  }
}
string[] paddedValues = new string[mytable.Columns.Count];
foreach (DataRow row in mytable.Rows) {
  for (int column = 0; column < mytable.Columns.Count; column++) {
    // add spaces in front of the value to make it align nicely
    paddedValues[column] = row.ItemArray[column].ToString().PadLeft(maxLengthPerColumn[column]);
  }
  builder3.AppendLine(string.Join(";", paddedValues));
}
File.WriteAllText(@".\test.txt", builder3.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("Data exported");
cnn.Close();
```